# Export last column of every sheet into text file

Tags: excel, vba, text

I have an Excel spreadsheet with many tabs. I'd like to export the last column of each sheet in a text file (all in the same file, the first line of the second sheet must go just after the last line of the fist sheet).

The thing is the number of columns changes from one sheet to another. The number of the last column can be given by the last non empty cell on the first row.

I've seen how to write in a file, but I'm clueless on how to iterate over sheets and rows...

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You could use a union query with ADO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the last cell in a row using this code:

```
Sub LastCellInRow()
   Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Select
End Sub
```

You can iterate through every Worsheet using the `Worksheets` collection:

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets() 
    Dim ws As Worksheet 
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 

         '** Perform code here **

    Next ws 
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok thanks. However, I don't get how to use `LastCellInRow` (it doesn't return a column index, does it?) to get the values of the cells.

Comment: This is an example, you should adapt it to your case using the properties of the object, for instance: `Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Value` to get the content of the cell

Comment: Be aware that finding the last column using `Range("IV1")` is specific to Excel 2003 (and maybe earlier).

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: that's true but it would work on any later version if you don't have data after that column (or else, you can adapt the column name)

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbDestination As Workbook
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim cumrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbDestination = Workbooks.Open("C:\destination.xls")

cumrow = 0
For Each s In wbSource.Worksheets
    lastcol = s.Cells(1, s.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastrow = s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, lastcol).End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = s.Cells(1, lastcol).Resize(lastrow, 1) ' This is your column

    ' Copy it to appropriate location on destination sheet
    wbDestination.Sheets(1).Cells(cumrow + 1, 1).Resize(lastrow, 1) = r
    cumrow = cumrow + lastrow
Next s
```

The above was written and tested while on a video conference call!